# gstreamer with N sources/producers and N consumers

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I have N cameras, each on different machines(producers). We need to send these camera video to 1 central server, from which N consumers can select and play selected video. Is this possible to achieve this over the network with gstreamer? If yes, what are the elements we have to use in this? Appreciate if anyone could help or give some pointers. Thanks!

[image]

I was able to achieve this in 2 ways as given in answer below

I couldn't find any example on **how to use input-selector** or **where do we mention which input to be selected and played**. Could you please provide an example? I tried tee. As I understand, with tee, I can play the data from producer 1 in 2 clients. i.e. same data can be split and given to N consumers. I couldn't find example to select and play with tee. Any pointers will be very helpful. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. One of way, I suggest is using `RTP/UDP` streaming. This is a case of a single server with many clients and can be handled easily using `RTP`.  Each producers can run a pipeline on the lines of :

```
v4l2src -> xenc -> codec_parse -> rtpxpay -> rtpbin.send_rtp -> udpsink host=<server _addr> -> rtpbin.send_rtcp udpsink host=<server_addr> -> udpsrc -> rtpbin.recv_rtcp
```

You can chose to ignore the `RTCP` in case your application does not require feedbacks about the network conditions, and packet transmission. 
At the server, you can run an element [`output selector`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-output-selector.html), that selects based on your application which camera source data to be displayed. 
You can also look into element [`tee`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html) instead of `output selector`, in case it suits your use case better.

Comment: ok,thanks @vk_gst .I am a beginner in gstreamer. Let me try to go through the pointers you have given.

Comment: i think i got the producer working.                                                                     
                                                                                                                          
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! rtpjpegpay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false async=false udpsrc ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0

Comment: could you pls suggest how a sample pipeline will look on the server side?

Comment: I believe without rtcp when app doesnt care about lost packets you meant following pipeline:  gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! rtpjpegpay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

Comment: At the server side :  `udpsrc -> rtpbin -> rtpjpegdepay -> jpeg_decoder ->  videosink`

Comment: Shouldn't we have a selector in the pipeline as you mentioned earlier? Because there are N producers sending streaming video data to same port on server.

Comment: Yes. The pipeline I mentioned was a minimal pipeline to reflect how the receiver works. Based on your application, add an `output selector` at an appropriate place, where you will have the knowledge of the RTP session (SSRC). Else, if your application has any other way to notify from which source the stream has generated, you can use that as an input to `output selector`. Ideally, I think you can place `output-selector` before `videosink`. Also take a look on element `input selector`. One of the two might help you. Simultaneous streaming is also possible using `tee`

Comment: I think, the payload type should not be meddled with. It specifies if its audio/video and so on. So this should be generated automatically in the rtpbin. You can also try querying the `CAPS` instead, which provides you the PT and SSRC.  Using different ports for different media types/seesions is the way to proceed further. Why look for other solutions? Add an edit to the question, or accept the answer and ask a new question. It is difficult to interpret the problem described in the comments.

Comment: I have edited the answer and removed the comments as you suggested. I still haven't achieved the required results. Need to have a way to select the different session data from data received on same port. If this is not possible, then will go with different ports. I will try with CAPS as mentioned

Comment: Ideally changing the sink pads of `[input-selector]`(https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-input-selector.html)  based on SSRC should give you what you need. I have never used input selector, but reading the documentation, it seems that it should suffice your use case.

Comment: input-selector might be the one to use. But I am not getting how to use this. An example usage on command-line(similar to all producers/receivers given in the question)is what I am looking for. That example would complete the answer to this question. Could you please help?

Comment: Your switching use case cannot be done using a command line interface.1.  You need to write a logic, that requests sink pads for `inputselector` (same as rtpbin). 2. Based on your SSRC, find a way to allow stream to pass through from sink to src pad of `inputselector` (look into adding probes for element pads)

Comment: say there are only 2 source and ssrc is 101 for one and 102 for another. cant we have commandline receiver which selects and play only 101?

Comment: I meant for command line switching logic is not required.Only hardcoded source should be played. Once I get the pipeline is working fine, I am planning to start with the program, using C or Java library

Comment: if you can create a sinkpad1 for ssrc 101, and keep it only active(hardcoded), and block sinkpad2 for ssrc 102, you can do it. Blocking pads require you to write a program in C/C++ or any other language. But it seems a dirty hack. I would still go with different ports for different data types. After all you can create 65535 ports for UDP/TCP

Comment: Yes, the plan is to go for different ports for now. Though I haven't got the sample for input selector, I have accepted this one as answer and given bounty, as this is the closest and the only one :). Thanks for the help! I will add another bounty when I have 50 in my bag :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this in 2 ways

**Approach 1)** each sender will be sending to different ports(0 - 65535) in the server. Here instead of camera using 2 mp4 files.

**producer1** : 
    `SRCID=1 PT=26 SERVER=127.0.0.1 PORT=5200 bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" filesrc location="video1.mp4" ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=$PT,clock-rate=90000,ssrc=(uint)$SRCID" ! r.send_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.send_rtp_src_$SRCID ! udpsink host=$SERVER port=$PORT'`

**producer2** : 
    `SRCID=1 PT=26 SERVER=127.0.0.1 PORT=5201 bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" filesrc location="video2.mp4" ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=$PT,clock-rate=90000,ssrc=(uint)$SRCID" ! r.send_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.send_rtp_src_$SRCID ! udpsink host=$SERVER port=$PORT'`

**receiver 1** (which plays data from port 5200): 
    `SRCID=1 PT=26 PORT=5200 CAPS_V="media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=$PT" bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" udpsrc port=$PORT ! "application/x-rtp,$CAPS_V" ! r.recv_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.recv_rtp_src_${SRCID}_${SRCID}_$PT ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink'`

**receiver 2** (which plays data from port 5201): 
    `SRCID=1 PT=26 PORT=5201 CAPS_V="media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=$PT" bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" udpsrc port=$PORT ! "application/x-rtp,$CAPS_V" ! r.recv_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.recv_rtp_src_${SRCID}_${SRCID}_$PT ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink'`

**Approach 2)** Now the second way is by changing the payload type and ssrc. But it doesn't seems to be a good approach, and also not correct approach. Because we dont have N payload type

**producer1** : 
    `SRCID= 1 PT=$((SRCID+100)) SERVER=127.0.0.1 PORT=5200 bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" filesrc location="video1.mp4" ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=$PT,clock-rate=90000,ssrc=(uint)$SRCID" ! r.send_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.send_rtp_src_$SRCID ! udpsink host=$SERVER port=$PORT'`

**producer2** : 
    `SRCID= 2 PT=$((SRCID+100)) SERVER=127.0.0.1 PORT=5200 bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" filesrc location="video2.mp4" ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=$PT,clock-rate=90000,ssrc=(uint)$SRCID" ! r.send_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.send_rtp_src_$SRCID ! udpsink host=$SERVER port=$PORT`

but in this case, with mp4 files I am able to play only one at a time. But when I tried with 2 webcams from 2 different machines, it played both simultaneously.

So receiver used is

**receiver1** (which plays srcid 1): 
    `SRCID=`**1** `PT=$((SRCID+100)) PORT=5200 CAPS_V="media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)JPEG,payload=$PT" bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" udpsrc port=$PORT ! "application/x-rtp,$CAPS_V" ! r.recv_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.recv_rtp_src_${SRCID}_${SRCID}_$PT ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink'`

and change SRCID to 2 to play the second video.

**receiver2** (which plays srcid 2): 
    `SRCID=`**2**`PT=$((SRCID+100)) PORT=5200 CAPS_V="media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)JPEG,payload=$PT" bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -e rtpbin name=r sdes="application/x-rtp-source-sdes" udpsrc port=$PORT ! "application/x-rtp,$CAPS_V" ! r.recv_rtp_sink_$SRCID r.recv_rtp_src_${SRCID}_${SRCID}_$PT ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink'`